# Saving a file to CSV in C#/ASP.NET with different encodings

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, encoding, csv

I do the following in my app:

```
 File.WriteAllText(OutPutFileName + InPutTitle + ".csv", OutputText, Encoding.UTF8);

 //outputText is a string of data separated by commas with line breaks
```

When I output with Encoding UTF8 and open the csv in Excel, each data point between commas is in each correct cell. But when I switch to Unicode or UTF32, the commas show up in excel and the data is on one long line.

How do I fix this while having encoding at UTF32 (I want this because I have certain chars that need displaying that don't come out in UTF8).

Comment: does that happen with any kind of delimiter , or only commas?

Comment: not sure, the app is too big to change delimiters since thats in the sql assembly generation

Comment: donot know precise but try for default encoding

Answer (score 2):

You might have to split that up into several lines. Use encoding UTF8 for the commas and other basic stuff, and only use UTF32 for what is needed.

Comment: oh that kinda sucks but makes sense

Comment: yeah it messes up if you alter encodings, so thats a no go